# taskkill with filter windowtitle does not work

Tags: windows

The system is Win 7 x64 Pro. Interface Explorer is classic, no aeroes etc. I have an explorer window with title

C:\

In a console I run

tasklist /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq C:\"

taskkill  /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq C:\"

tasklist /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq *"

All the commands above result filter not recognized. Many other windows were checked with the same result. Any ideas?

PS. On the other hand when running

tasklist /fi "Windowtitle eq C*"

I get several conhost.exe which are not windows at all The following two commands give the same result under absense of any windows except console windows itself.

tasklist /fi "username eq User" /fi "windowtitle ne xxx"

tasklist /fi "username eq User" /fi "imagename ne xxx"

Seems the same effect for imagename and for window title...? User here is just me as admin.

Comment: Some further experiments lead, perhaps, to more nonsenses.

Comment: The following two commands give the same results under absense of any windows except console windows itself